# I need helping making an insert function for this vector class

Tags: c++, class, vector

Call your driver "vector_test_driver.cpp", and your class implementation file "VLIST.cpp". Define the following behavior for VLIST:

1. Implement a default constructor. Include the following message, "*Default Constructor Invoked*"  every time the function is called.
2. Implement a copy constructor to perform a deep copy of a VLIST object. Include the following message, "*Copy Constructor Invoked*" every time the function is called. The function should also print the contents of each VLIST object on single separate lines.
3. Implement the destructor.  Include the following message, "*Destructor Invoked*" every time the function is called.
4. Implement `Is_Full()` which returns true if full; otherwise false;  Include the message, "*Is_Full Invoked*” every time the function is called.
5. Implement `Is_Empty()` which returns true if empty; otherwise false;  Include the message, "*Is_Empty Invoked*”     every time the function is called.
6. Implement the member function called "Search" to search the vector for an item. The function should print the message, “*Item Found*” or “*Item Not Found*”.  Which message is print depends on if the item was found or not found in the vector.  Print the item (search key) you were looking for.   Include the following message, "*Search Invoked*" every time the function is called.
7. Implement a function called "Insert" to add an item to the vector in order (alphabetical order). The function should print the contents of the VLIST object before and after the function has been executed on single separate lines.  Include the following message, "*Insert Invoked*" every time the function is called.
8. Implement a function called "Remove" to remove an item from the vector. The function should print the contents of the VLIST object before and after the function has been executed on single separate lines.  Include the following message, "*Remove Invoked*" every time the function is invoked.

Here my class definition:

```
class VLIST
{
public:
//VLIST();                //default constructor
//VLIST(const VLIST  &);  //copy constructor
//~VLIST();               //destructor
//bool IsEmpty();         //return true if empty; otherwise false
//bool IsFull();         //return true if full; otherwise false
//vector<string>::iterator Search(const string &); //returns the location of the string in the dynamic array
//void Insert(const string & key); //add key to dynamic array if not full; otherwise prints a message stating dynamic array is full
//void Remove(const string & key); //removes key from dynamic array if it is there; otherwise prints a message stating it was not in dynamic array; the function using an iterator and the erase function to remove an item from the vector.
//void Print(); //Print every string in the array
//other functions may be implemented if necessary
private:
// VLIST<string> DB;  //vector
//additonal state variables you may wish add
};
```

My code for the insert function so far;

```
 void VLIST::Insert(const string & key) {
        cout << "Insert invoked" << endl;

        vector<string>::iterator vec;
        vec = DB[count].begin();
        DB[count].at(1) = key;

        count++;
        }
```

I'm kinda just taking shots in the dark.  I'm sure a friend function would probably help me access Db since its in the private field. But I was trying to adhere to the skeleton given to me. I'm not sure how to implement the vector correctly to have strings inserted into it in one function and printed into another function. **I don't want the whole assignment done, i just want to see how the insert function could be implemented**

The print function I've come up with so far:

```
void VLIST::Print() {

    for (int i = 0; i < count;i++) {
        cout << " " << DB[count].at(i) << endl;
    }
```

Comment: 1.  Show us what you have so far.  (SO is not a "write your homework" service).  2.  How do you propose to indicate that Search did not find the string?  3.  Search should return vector<string>::const_iterator (otherwise you can write to things), or (better) `const string*` (which allows you to return `nullptr` for "no such string".  4.  The result from "Search" will be invalid after a call to Insert.  5.  How do you plan to *use* Search?  Perhaps it should just return `bool`.  6. `DB` should be a  `vector<string>`, not a `VLIST<string>`.

Comment: 7.  If DB is a std::vector, what do they mean by "full"?  8. In fact, if that header was handed out as part of the assignment, I think I would complain.

Comment: Im sorry, not to discredit my professor or anything, but i was just trying to see how one function is done so i could do the rest, vectors (atleast i assumed) were similar to arrays but im having difficulty implementing vectors. I didnt post the whole assignment because i wanted to do the rest myself, heres the whole assignment

Answer (score 1):

You have to "implement" an insertion sort for `std::vector`. Its not clear why your professor calls this data structure a list but forces you to use a dynamic array (probably to imitate one). I would do something like this. Don't mind the assertions.

```
  void Insert(const std::string& key)
  {
     std::cout << "Insert Invoked.\n";
     print_db(std::cout);
     assert(std::is_sorted(std::begin(db_), std::end(db_))); // Expects(std::is_sorted(db_));

     db_.push_back(key);
     auto insert_pos = std::upper_bound(std::begin(db_), std::end(db_)-1, key);
     std::rotate(insert_pos, std::end(db_)-1, std::end(db_));

     assert(std::is_sorted(std::begin(db_), std::end(db_))); // Ensures(std::is_sorted(db_));
     print_db(std::cout);
  }
```

Here is a [Demo](https://ideone.com/G6rhAF).

Look carefully at what I have done and try to fit it into your model. Instead of `std::upper_bound` try to use your `Search` method and so on.

One thing you should take generally with you is the idea to reuse the algorithms which are provided by the Standard. Look up what `std::rotate` and `std::upper_bound` do (for `RandomAccessIterator`s).

If you implement a binary search for yourself, look for how many comparisons you exactly do because `std::string` comparisons can be very costly. You can do a `binary_search` with 'exactly' `log(n)` comparisons (one comparison per loop, not two or similar).